# How to use variable values from another flow on mule?

Tags: session, mule

Im trying to access a value from session variable set into another flow

code:

```
<flow name="test" doc:name="test" >
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8081/services/autocomplete" connector-ref="" transformer-refs="transform" doc:name="HTTP">
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <set-variable variableName="req" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.string']]" doc:name="Variable"/>

    <set-session-variable variableName="message" value="test" doc:name="Set Message ID"/>

    <http:outbound-endpoint host="teste.local" path="newlocation/autocomplete?#[groovy:return req.toString();]" port="8080" user="login" password="1234" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

and another flow trying to print it:

```
<flow name="test2" doc:name="test2" >
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8081/services/autocomplete2" connector-ref="" transformer-refs="transform" doc:name="HTTP">
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <set-variable variableName="req" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.string']]" doc:name="Variable"/>

    <logger message="#[sessionVars.message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <http:outbound-endpoint host="teste.local" path="newlocation/autocomplete?#[groovy:return req.toString();]" port="8080" user="login" password="1234" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

But there is an error saing there is no variable set into that flow even when i first try to access the first url them i change to the seccond where it was supose to have the session.

-> mule version 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session variables need to be passed from one flow to another. They are serialized and deserialized on the event. You're setting it in the first flow and calling /autocomplete but the flow thats reading it is listening on /autocomplete2.

You cannot hit /autocomplete2 separately after /autocomplete and expect the session variable to be there as it was set on a different event. If you are looking to store state between separate flow invocations take a look at the mule objectstore module

http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-objectstore/mule/objectstore-config.html

And info on Mule object stores here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Object+Stores

Some example configurations here:

https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-objectstore/blob/master/src/test/resources/mule-config.xml

Comment: Hi thank you for your feedback, that may answer my problem i will take a look and try, do you have any sample code that i can base to implement mine?

Comment: Updated answer with link to example configs. Note you'll need to add the objectstore module via Maven etc.

Comment: Well i cant find the schema for objectStore... so it keeps giving me an error, now mulesoft just dont provide it... any clue where can i find it?

Answer (score 0):

Your flow will be something like the following :-

```
<flow name="test" doc:name="test" >
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8081/services/autocomplete" doc:name="HTTP">
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <set-variable variableName="req" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.string']]" doc:name="Variable"/>

    <set-session-variable variableName="message" value="test" doc:name="Set Message ID"/>
        <logger message="Done #[sessionVars.message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://localhost:8081/services/autocomplete2" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>

<flow name="test2" doc:name="test2" >
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8081/services/autocomplete2"  doc:name="HTTP">
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <set-variable variableName="req" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.string']]" doc:name="Variable"/>

    <logger message="#[sessionVars.message] #[sessionVars['message']] " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>


</flow>
```